# How were khutbahs given before invention of microphone?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, history, khutbah

How exactly did the Imam read the Qirat or deliver a Khutbah in the past before the invention of the microphone so as to make a group of 1000 - 2000 people hear him?

In some case the population would reach 10000 as was the case of hajj in the past. 
How exactly was it it possible for such a huge population to pray behind one imam and still be able to hear his Qirat or his Khutbah?

Comment: It is not necessary to hear the Imam to follow him.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely it was not possible for 10000 people to listen Imam without microphone. There's no hidden magic that you're looking forward.

But for prayers, Takbeerat were recalled by persons in mid to be audible to farthest.

Comment: This only answers the part about prayer not that about the khotba.